# When should I use getElementById?

Tags: javascript

I'm an experienced developer, but new to javascript.  I can't figure out when I should use the whole "document.getElementById(e.id).value" and when I can just use "e".  I'm looking at a tiny existing function in a common functions script that uses both.

> function RemoveFormat(e) {
>   document.getElementById(e.id).value =
>   cleanNumber(document.getElementById(e.id).value);
>   e.select(); }

(where cleanNumber is another common function)

Presumably there are circumstances that make the extra typing necessary, but what are they?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example demonstrates when you have a reference to the element you want to control. If you already have a reference to the element, there is no reason to use `document.getElementById` to obtain a reference to it (you already have one):

```
<span id="mySpan" onclick="test(this);">TEST</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(el) {
    // el is a reference to an element, you can use it directly
    el.style.display = 'none';

    // to demonstrate that the element you retrieve from gEBI 
    // with el.id is the same as your original reference
    var elAgain = document.getElementById(el.id);
    alert(elAgain === el); // "true"
}
</script>
```

The place where you might want to use `document.getElementById` is when you want to control another element to which you don't already have a reference:

```
<span id="mySpan" onclick="test(this, 'myDiv');">TEST</span>
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none;">DIV REVEALED</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(el, otherElId) {
    // el is a reference to an element, you can use it directly
    el.style.display = 'none';
    // otherElId is a string containing the id of
    // the element you want to control
    var theDiv = document.getElementById(otherElId);
    theDiv.style.display = '';
}
</script>
```

Note that there is rarely (if ever) a reason to do something like the following:

```
<span id="mySpan" onclick="test('mySpan');">TEST</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(theElId) {
    var el = document.getElementById(theElId);
    el.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

If the function is being fired from an element event, you can just pass `this` (as per my first example), rather than passing the id of the element the event is happening on.

Comment: Thank you very much, not only for the answer but for educating me for the more-to-come.

Answer (score 5):

if `e` is the node, there's no need to write `document.getElementById(e.id)`, you will get the same.

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementById() just looks for a DOM object by a given ID (string) and returns it if it's found.

But **e** in this case is just an arbitrary variable that might be an DOM object, or it might be something like a string.  It depends on the context of the rest of your source code.

**getElementById() is necessary** if your code looks like this:

```
<input id="mytext" type="text" onchange="RemoveFormat('mytext')" />
```

**getElementById() is unnecessary** if your code looks like this:

```
<input id="mytext" type="text" onchange="RemoveFormat(this)" />
```

The "this" part will pass a reference to the DOM object (a textbox in this case) which is really what you're after.  So document.getElementById is unnecessary.  The same example could be applied to the click of a button, onmouseover of a link, etc, etc.

Generally I prefer to use the "this" method whenever possible since it'll clean up your javascript.  But sometimes it's not suitable.  So then I use a naming convention in the javascript that helps me remember which method I used.  Like I'll use the variable name of e for a DOM object, or id for a string.  This should help you keep it straight in your code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to do this.

```
e.value = cleanNumber(e.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it your passing the element into your function but to get the element from the dom you would do:

```
var e = document.getElementById('elementId')
```

Answer (score 0):

Precisely speaking, the function

```
function f (e) {
    return document.getElementById(e.id);
}
```

is the identity function everywhere it is defined, *assuming* that e is in document.

Answer (score 0):

window.nodeId is a non-standard IE extension -- and only present in the most recent versions of firefox, and it logs a warning whenever you make use of this.  But the other issues are that if anyone ever defines a variable or function that has a name that conflicts with a node identifier then that variable or function overrides your node reference.

Together these specifics mean that you cannot guarantee entirely correct behaviour when using window.nodeId whereas document.getElementById always works correctly.